# Match the phrase that have first char capitalized

Tags: regex

I want to match the phrase that have every first char capitalized before the word 'users'.

**For example:**

**I've a string :** to Apple Tablet users or anything for Apple Tablet users

**The result after matching must be :** Apple Table

**or** anything-without-first-char-capitalized-here Abc users => Abc

**or** anything-without-first-char-capitalized-here Abc Def users => Abc Def

**or** anything-without-first-char-capitalized-here Abc Def Xyz users => Abc Def Xyz

What i've try : `(((?-i)[A-Z][a-z]*) )*users`
But it's only matching the first word - **Tablet**

Comment: Apple Tablet is coming tow times, you want it once only

Comment: for ex it has to "Apple Tablet users or anything for Apple Tablet users, Evan is Shopping" then what will it return

Comment: The regular expression itself is correct. More likely you are using your regex library functions in a wrong way. Can you paste the code?

Comment: Apple Tablet is not a single word, it contains two words

Comment: Yes, i want to match 1 word, 2 word or even 3 word if they have first char capitalized.

Comment: if you use python, use re.findall

Comment: @metaphy re.findall will not change the outcome with that regular expression :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of correctly grouping:

```
((?:(?-i)[A-Z][a-z]* )*)users
```

You could perhaps do this if you don't want to get the last space in the capture:

```
((?:(?-i)[A-Z][a-z]* ??)*?)\s*users
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/nU4iD8)

---

```
(((?-i)[A-Z][a-z]*) )*
^^----------------^ ^
|_________1_________|
          2
```

The first (inner) capture deals with the words, the second (outer) capture adds the space. You can easily combine the two in a single group (hence why you find `(?:(?-i)[A-Z][a-z]* )` in my regex.

Then the issue is that the last capture is being repeated and this is what causes only `Tablet` to be capture in the first capture group. Compare with how the ultimate capture group  is not repeated in the regex I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use quantification to match multiple upper case words.  Then use a look ahead to find users but not include it in the result.

```
(?:\b[A-Z][a-z]*\s*)+(?=\busers\b)
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/2ygbtz)

[REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/2ygbtz) has a working example with all of your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
(([A-Z]+[\w-]*[\s])+users)
```

[image: Matches are below]

[image: Explanation here]